# has_and_belongs_to_many sorted relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I have a `Group` model that has `has_and_belongs_to_many :activities`.

For each `Group`, the associated `Activity` needs to be sorted/ranked by a `position` field. I don't think I can add a field/column called `position` in `Activity` model because a `Group` can have multiple `Activities` and a `Activity` can be in multiple `Groups`.

Any ideas on how to model this?

I'm using Mongoid 3, but I'd think the solution would be similar with ActiveRecord.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put a property that is inherent to the relation in the join table. For that you need to convert `habtm` to `has_many :through`.

Here is a [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000605/how-to-implement-has-many-through-relationships-with-mongoid-and-mongodb) that details how to implement `has_many :through` in Mongoid as it is not supported by default.

So in this case, the join table `activity_groups` can have a column called `position`.