# Mongoid and user groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, associations, has-many-through

I'm new to mongoid and have stumbled onto a problem. I have a user model and a group model and I want the users to be able to create groups and another user to join that group. with my experience from AR i would solve this via has_many :through but with mongoid i don't have this option.

I've been trying this solution [How to implement has_many :through relationships with Mongoid and mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000605/how-to-implement-has-many-through-relationships-with-mongoid-and-mongodb) But I'm not able to get @group.users.

I would appreciate all possible help. :)

Comment: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_and_belongs_to_many

Comment: ^ that should be the answer

Comment: Thank you! That was my first impuls. What would a good action look like for a user to join a group. I must admit that i've never used HABTM before.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end

class Group
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

u = User.create!(name: "arthurnn")
g = Group.create!(users: [u])
```