# Mongoid get models from many to many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I have `User`, `Shop` and `FavouriteShop` models. I'm using mongoid:

```
class User
   include Mongoid::Document
   has_many :favourite_shops, dependent: :destroy
end

class Shop
   include Mongoid::Document
   has_many :favourite_shops, dependent: :destroy
end

class FavouriteShop
   include Mongoid::Document
   include Mongoid::Timestamps

   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :shop
end
```

As you can see, there is many-to-many relationship with `User` and `Shop` via `FavouriteShop`.

Now If I got one user:

```
user = User.all.first
```

How can I get all Shops which are associatied to User?

Comment: what about `user.favourite_shopts.map(&:shop)`?

Comment: That worked. Could your descriibe your solution?

Comment: see the answer below, although I do not believe that this kind of relation is the best way in mongoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using  `user.favourite_shops.map(&:shop)` you simply call the `#shop` on each of the user's favourite_shops and receiver an array of related shops. In other word, you replace each of the `favourite_shops` with the associated `shop`.

If you wanted to do that a Mongoid way , please consider this post [How to implement has_many :through relationships with Mongoid and mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000605/how-to-implement-has-many-through-relationships-with-mongoid-and-mongodb).

Comment: You mentioned that it is not best relation in mongoid. why? I think there will be additional information in `FavouriteShop` model.

Comment: If you are going to add more data to the `FavouriteShop` then it is finde andsuitable :). But if used only as a M:N resolution entity, I would trash it:).