# How to pass params in link to - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How should I pass the params about the article category. I have a Article which belongs to Article category. When I click to this   `<%= link_to @article.name, article_categories_path%>`, I want to see the all articles in this category. So I have to pass the params through it to ArticleCategoryController.  Is my link to statement correct ? Now I get a "Article" instead of the category name( when I click it I'm getting the error:   `Document.find expects the parameters to be 1 or more ids,`).

**Article model**

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :title, type: String
  field :content, type: String

  belongs_to :user
  #kategorie
  belongs_to :article_category
```

**Article controler**

```
  class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def article
    @article = Article.order_by(created_at: 'desc').page params[:page]
  end

  def view_article
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**ArticleCategory model**

```
class ArticleCategory
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps


  field :name, type: String

  has_many :articles


end
```

Routes

```
  resources :article_categories do
  resources :articles, shallow: true
  end
```

ArticleCategories Controller

```
class ArticleCategoriesController < ApplicationController

   def index
     @category = ArticleCategory.find(params[:id])
     @articles = @category.articles
   end
 end
```

**Article view**

```
<p>Category: <%= link_to @article.name, article_categories_path%>
            Tagi: <%= link_to "Tagi", tags_path %> </p>
```

Comment: what do your routes look like..

Comment: Why are you sending an article name as your first argument in your `link_to`?  Not sure what you are intending.

Answer (score 1):

the way I would normally do something like this is with a has many through. (also I would check your models, since it looks like you have the belongs_to/has_many backwards, belongs_to goes in the model with foreign keys)..

```
class Article
   has_many :article_categories
   has_many :categories, through: :article_categories
end

class ArticleCategory
   belongs_to: :article
   belongs_to: :category
end

class Category
   has_many :article_categories
   has_many: articles, through: :article_categories
end
```

Then if you would like to see all Articles in a given category. then you can do it via the CategoriesController

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
    ....
    def show
       @category = Category.find params[:id]
    end 

 end
```

and then you should be able to get all the articles via @category.articles association.

Since the way you are doing it now you will only get the 1 category via the article_category table.

In response to comment..

Each article is going to have multiple categories..

So you would have something like this.

```
 <% @article.categories.each do |cat| %>
   <%= link_to cat.name, cat %> <br />
 <% end %>
```

Formatted however you would like.  This assumes you have a `resources :categories` in your routes, and `Category` has a name field

Comment: Good idea, so now how  should i link to the category in the Article view?

Comment: After update i'm getting Mongoid Problem:
  I`nvalid option :through provided to relation :categories.`

Comment: Ahh looks like mongoid doesn't support that.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000605/how-to-implement-has-many-through-relationships-with-mongoid-and-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

`<%= link_to "All", article_categories_path(@category) %>`

Provided you've got @category variable set, this will take you to /article_categories/:id